# Downloading two different file types with Selenium

Tags: java, firefox, selenium

I've got a program that downloads a couple different files throughout the course of the script. Some files are Zip files while others are CSV files. I want to be able to download each set of files without the browser popup asking where I want to save to. I've set a Firefox browser preference, and it works great with the Zip file, but when I try and add the CSV Mime type, it still gives me the popup. Am I doing this wrong, or should I be using a different Mime type?

```
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/zip" + "text/csv");
```

Comment: what about a comma between mime types in a preference?

Comment: I tried that, bu that just causes errors, and wont allow the program to run.

Comment: try to remove zip and leave only csv type. if it works, the problem is not in mime type, but in a parameter

Comment: Just tried that, and I still got the popup, which leads me to believe it's an issue with the mime type. Upon further inspection the file seems to be a `Microsoft Excel Comma Separated Values File` but everything I seem to find online points to still using a `text/csv` mime type.

Comment: hmmm. try application/vnd.ms-excel mime type then

Comment: Already did, and it didn't work unfortunately.